# UIView reference error

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, swift3

I have created UIView in storyboard (Xcode 8.2.1). I reference the things inside to UIView class name `LoginView`. I delete one things by mistake then I got error at the line of `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LoginView", owner: self, options: nil)`. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,....)`  I read about this in some answer here, they said about referencing missing. I try to reference everything again but still error. I'm now confusing about what should I reference it to. File Owner or View.

EDIT : The bug is happen when this View is render.

**LoginView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class LoginView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var view: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var forgotPasswordBtn: UIButton!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LoginView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
        emailField.becomeFirstResponder()

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

This is my components in LoginView StoryBoard

[image]

And this is my referencing.

[image]

Comment: Have you try `self.endEditing(true)`?

Comment: Where should I put that ? can you explain please i'm really newbie

Comment: Try to remove the reference on LoginView from project and add then again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a CocoaPod called [NibDesignable](https://github.com/mbogh/NibDesignable) that not only configures the nib into the view (with constraints), but also makes the view `IBDesignable` so you can see your nib-based-views in the storyboard.

*NibDesignable requires you to change the nib's file owner to the view class rather than the nib's view's custom class. Also, outlet connections must be made from the file's owner and not from the nib's view.*

```
@IBDesignable class LoginView: NibDesignable {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var forgotPasswordBtn: UIButton!

    // MARK: Properties

    var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer? {
        willSet {
            tap.flatMap { removeGestureRecognizer($0) }
        }
        didSet {
            tap.flatMap { addGestureRecognizer($0) }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(didRecognizeTapGesture)
        )

        emailField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func didRecognizeTapGesture() {

        endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just BTW it looks like that one also comes as **Carthage**, since cocoapods is unusable / deprecated now.